# AMPScript and email templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

Everything with AMPScript...

Is it possible to send an email with custom fields?

I develop a landing page with a lot of input fields... I was wondering if it is possible to send a template-based email with some custom fields (from inputs of before), like a contact form page

I read this: [Create a Triggered Send for an On-Your-Behalf-Account](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_examples/create_a_triggered_send_for_an_on_your_behalf_account/)

and this: [Create a Triggered Send Using AMPScript and the SOAP Web Service API](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/create_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_web_service_api/)

but I don't understand those examples...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.  You'll need to:

1. Create a [**Triggered Send-Templated Data Extension**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/procedures/) that contains the columns from your form
2. Create a Triggered Send Definition that points to your email and the Triggered Send-Templated Data Extension
3. Start your Triggered Send Definition
4. In your landing page, add the [**AMPScript API code**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/create_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_web_service_api/) to fire off the email with the attribute values from your form.

Comment: Ty Adam! you are awesome! One question: I got  my "triggered send definition" created and started. I got an external key and a Name of that "triggered Send". Is the "CustomerKey ObjectProperty" (I mean in AMPScript code) where I write my "triggered send definition" external key for trigger that "email"? I'm not getting how this works,

Comment: Yes, that's correct.